# How to fetch current year and month from MySQL in JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to fetch the records from MySQL for the current year and month.

I am passing to get the today records

Today:
("recDate","=", new Date());

Like that, how to fetch for current Month and current Year ?

Thanks in advance

- Gnaniyar Zubair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CalendarExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int dom = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int doy = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        System.out.println("Current Date: " + cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Day: " + day);
        System.out.println("Month: " + month);
        System.out.println("Year: " + year);
        System.out.println("Day of Week: " + dow);
        System.out.println("Day of Month: " + dom);
        System.out.println("Day of Year: " + doy);
    }
}
```

Here is the result of this example:

Current Date: Thu Dec 29 13:41:09 ICT 2005
 Day: 29
Month: 12
Year: 2005
Day of Week: 5
Day of Month: 29
Day of Year: 363

Comment: Please do not use other peoples code withtout giving them credit: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/21.html

Comment: Nothing wrong in learning from others and guiding other who don't know.

Comment: I think there is a difference between "learning from others" and copy&paste without citing your source. Agree?

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to pass parameters, MySQL can work out for itself what the current year and month is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE  YEAR(recDate) =  YEAR(CURDATE())
  AND MONTH(recDate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

or, alternatively,

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(recDate, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact functions in mysql but you google them. In your SQL in java code use CONVERT function on the date column and equate it to current date which alos uses the convert function. The Convert function will strip down the dates to only month and year and that way it will compared as string only.